# Generate url only when anchor is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic-linking

Is it possible to assign url to the an anchor only when it got clicked?

```
<a href="http://example.com/">Token Link</a>
```

When the anchor got clicked, it will go to http://example.com/token=xxxxx/

I want to generate token only when it got clicked.

If possible, How?

thanks

Comment: Yes, you can do it by adding a click handler to the link and setting `window.location` from there.

Comment: This is how Google Search does it's tracking of links, while also showing you the URL in the browser when you hover over the link. Also if bots are trying to cheat the system to make their sites look more popular, they will get a direct URL to the site instead of the tracking code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening the link in another window using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".thisClass a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // this prevents going to the original url or default behavior
    var changedLink = $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "/token=xxxx");
    var newUrl = $(changedLink).attr('href');
    window.open(newUrl, '_blank');

  });

});
```

// Here is a way to do it with Plain Javascript - i did not test it on all browsers but worked with chrome for example.

```
// goes in a script.js or in script tags under the </body> element
function changeTheLink() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var aLink = document.getElementById('theLink');
  var theOldLink = aLink.getAttribute("href");
  aLink.setAttribute('href', theOldLink + "/token=xxxx");
  var theNewLink = aLink.getAttribute("href");
  window.open(theNewLink, "_blank");

}
// here is the HTML you owuld have to add an id and an onclick attribute to use this code

 <div class="thisClass"><a href="http://thiswebsite.com" id="theLink"
 onclick="changeTheLink()">Here is a link</a></div>
```

Comment: looking at the code, "token=xxxx" is already there before it got clicked. or am I wrong?

Comment: not that I see when i test it in jsbin.com http://jsbin.com/qonif/1/edit - and it shouldn't bc all of the actions to the link are defined as the "event handler" function (the function() after the "click" handler is defined) - so once it is clicked that function goes into action. One last point in the jsbin example - you will see the token=xxxx disappear after a slipt second in the browser address bar - bc the url that I used does not have that page and it redirects it to the home. You can test that out by just copying and pasting the url into a browser and it will have the same reaction

Comment: I see. it looks like it could work on my application. is it doable with js only. no jquery?

Comment: Sure you could do it with plain JavaScript but libraries like jQuery are like the swiss army knife to working with all the different browsers at once. I could go into it more - but overall when working with the DOM (Browser API) it is best to use a library. Plain Javascript is still mixed in with jQuery - ie. `window.open...` in the code above. To use jQuery just put the link in header: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`  - if you already new that - my apologies.

Comment: added a plain javascript version

Answer (score 1):

you can handle the event and change the href like this.

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
   $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "/token=xxxx");
});
```

you can also directly navigate the user to a different url, without changing.

```
$("a").on("click", function(ev) {
   document.location.href = "//something-different.com";
   ev.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

Comment: looking at the code, "token=xxxx" or "something-different.com" is already there before it got clicked. or am I wrong?